# I want to change a ternary operator into if and else statement

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

When I changed the code below into if and else statement and log it into the console, I got function instead of 'beer'. How can i make it log 'beer' into the console using if and else statement

```js
const age = 26;

const beverage = age >= 21 ? "beer" : "Juice"

console.log(beverage)
```

Below is my code

```js
const age = 26;

const beverage = function(age) {
  if(age >= 21) {
    return 'beer'
  } else {
    return 'juice'
  }
}
console.log(beverage)
```

Comment: You're assigning a function to `beverage` now, not the result of an expression. You need to actually call the function to get the returned result: `console.log(beverage(age));`

Answer (score 2):

Because you didn't execute the function ( without execution of the function the console will log the function body )

```js
const age = 26;

const beverage = function(age) {
  if(age >= 21) {
    return 'beer'
  } else {
    return 'juice'
  }
}
console.log(beverage(age))
```